Mate in 2 by Vladimir Nabokov
White to move and mate in 2.

Attribution:  Vladimir Nabokov

rot13(Jbhyqa'g Xo6 or n zngr va 1? Be rira Xs6)

@Novarg the knight is pinned by the bishop

@PDT thanks, I totally missed that (facepalm)

Thanks for the edit.


 1.Qh5

seems to cover everything:

 1. .. b6 2. Ra7#
 1. .. e6 or e5 2.Qxf7#
 1. .. Bxd5+ 2.Qxd5#
 1. .. Bg6 or xh5 2.Nb6#
 1. .. Be6,e8 or g8 2.Q(x)e8#



King to b4. Then either Queen to D5 or Knight to B6, depending on whether black takes the knight.


But what about 1. ...e6?

Welcome to PSE (Puzzling Stack Exchange)!
